# Error: unclassifiable statement in fortran in ux=cos(theta)sin(phi)

Tags: fortran

I want to write a program in FORTRAN which calculate the detection efficiency for a punctual source  at a distance from the detector .The disc detector is assumed to be perfect: ie photon absorbing everything that falls on it. So here I am working in 3D and I use ux, uy and uz to lead the photon randomly using the spherical coordinate system;

efficiency vs the detector radius

Here is the bare code for punctual source:

```
program sourceponc

integer i,N
real  x,y,z,eff,count,Dds,rd,ux,uy,uz,t

count=0
do i=1,N
  theta = acos(1-2*rand())
  phi = 2*pi*rand()
  ux=cos(theta)sin(phi)
  uy=sin(theta)sin(phi)
  uz=cos(theta)

  t=Dds/uz
  x=ux*t
  y=uy*t

  if(sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2).le.1)then
    count=count+1
  endif
end do 

eff=count/N
print*,eff

end
```

I keep getting these error while compiling:

```
sourceponc.f90:11:

ux=cos(theta)sin(phi)
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
sourceponc.f90:12:

uy=sin(theta)sin(phi)
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

Can someone please help me with the following?

Answer (score 0):

Before asking your next question take some time to learn how to format code, and other text, in your questions.  Investigate the icons above the text box, the one you need first is the one that looks like **{ }**.

OK, so this

```
ux=cos(theta)sin(phi)
```

looks like a thoughtless translation from the mathematics.  Try

```
ux=cos(theta)*sin(phi)
```

Most programming languages don't automatically multiply adjacent terms, they have to be told more precisely what to do.  The compiler tells you the statement is unclassifiable because it cannot parse it, the statement is not syntactically valid Fortran.

PS In English you should write *point source* rather than *punctual source*.  Punctual has acquired the meaning of *on time* or *doing something at the agreed or right time*.